# Regex in a line replacement

Tags: java, regex, replace, line

I have this line in a text file which is in the following format:

```
/ text
 /
```

I need to edit the line and remove text and have a result like this:

```
/ 
 /
```

What regex should I use to remove the text? I have a problem because one "/" is in the line below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
public String doMagic()
{
    return "/\n /";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regexp if line "/" starts and you don't need anything after it:

```
String in = "/ text\n /";
String pattern = "^(/)(.+?)(\\n.*)";
System.out.println(in.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$3"));
```

Comment: Your answer is for JavaScript. The Original Poster has a file, so this is for Java.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to remove all characters after a "/" you can do:

```
String in = "/ text\n /";
String out = in.replaceAll("/.*", "/");
```